# fuzzysearch operation on python dict

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzy-search

I have a large dictionary in python where I need to compare all strings against all using fuzzy search. I'm using the fuzzywuzzy package.

However, the script is too slow and was wondering if someone could help me make it faster.

The code looks like this:

```
outfile = open('out.csv', 'w')
grouped = []
### a chunk of the dict, in reality it is around 100000 unique ID
d = {'1':'{'Name':'Jason Bourne', 'Code':'1234'}', '2':'{'Name':'Jasen Bourne', 'Code':'1234'}','3':'{'Name':'Jason Boune', 'Code':'12345'}'}

for id1, id2 in itertools.combinations(d.keys(),2):
     score = fuzz.partial_ratio(d[id1]['Name'],d[id2]['Name'])
     if id1 in grouped and id2 in grouped:
          continue
     if score > 80 and d[id1]['Code']==d[id2]['Code']:
         grouped.append(id2)
         outfile.write(id1, id2, d[id1]['Name'])
```

Comment: (1) You could use a set instead of a list for `grouped` which would make the membership test more efficient. (2) You could defer calculating `score` until after checking `id1 in grouped and id2 in grouped`. (3) You could cache the results of the `d[id1]` and `d[id2]` lookups in local variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the given example, grouping the items by `'Code'` first would likely speed things up considerably.

Regardless, you should be trying to avoid comparing every string with every other string, since for 100k strings (10^5) that is about 10 billion (10^10) comparisons.

One relatively simple process that could be much faster:

1. Create an n-gram index of all of the strings (after normalizing case, whitespace etc.)
2. Search for near-matches of each string using that index, then fully compare just with those.